# how to pass parameter to trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

i need to add one number to post.like_count where post.id = like.module_id
! like.module_id definition when insert into the like table

(post table)
id
user_id
like_count

(like tabel)
id
module_id
like

(like table trigger)

```
DELIMITER $$CREATE TRIGGER update_LikeCount 
AFTER INSERT ON like FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN      
    UPDATE post SET hpost.like_count = post.like_count + 1       
    WHERE post.id = like.module_id;  
END 
$$DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: So you want the trigger to update a row in `post` with the `module_id` of the "like" you just inserted, correct?

Comment: Can't you do this from the application? Triggers are very easy too forget and not debuggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the fields of the row you are about to insert with the `NEW` keyword (just as you would use the table name):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER ...
UPDATE post SET hpost.like_count = post.like_count + 1       
WHERE post.id = NEW.module_id; 
...
```

Notice the `OLD` keyword is also available to `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` triggers.

---

Just a side note regarding the relevance of this trigger at all. You seem to be trying to pre-calculate the number of "likes" for a given post. Unless your tables get really, really large and your database really, really busy, a query like this should be virtually instant, and gives you the guarantee to always return accurate, up-to-date figures, without the need to implement a complicated maintenance:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(module_id) FROM likes WHERE module_id = [the post id] ;
```

You might want to reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any nasty little hacks you cant really pass parameters to triggers (they are independent of the code that triggered them which could come from anywhere (app code, management console etc))

Looks to me like you might want to change your architecture a little to incorporate the user id into the like table...

(i might not have understood the scenario correctly so please update with more info if you think it will help!)